# Can I show 2 field from one table and one counted row from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I want to show `UserName`, `UserEmail` from `td_users` and no of rows of same `UserEmail` from `td_add_service`. My table structure is given below

table  td_users

```
id | UserName | UserEmail| 
------------------------------
1  | abdul   | abdul@gmail.com
------------------------------
2  | Rahim   | rahim@gmail.com
------------------------------
3  | Karim   | karim@gmail.com
------------------------------

table  td_add_service
    ---------------------------------------------------
id | serviceName |  serviceDeatails        | UserEmail| 
------------------------------------------------------
1  | Servi1      |   testserviceone        | abdul@gmail.com
--------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Servi11     | testserviceonev         | rahim@gmail.com
---------------------------------------------------------------
3  | Servi111    |  testserviceone1        | karim@gmail.com
---------------------------------------------------------------
4  | Servi111    |  testserviceone2        | karim@gmail.com
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

id is primary key for both table

I want to show data like

```
    ---------------------------------------------------
  Username |  UserMail            | No of Services| 
------------------------------------------------------
  Abdul  |  abdul@gmail.com       | 1
------------------------------------------------------
Rahim    | rahim@gmail.com        | 1
---------------------------------------------------
Karim    |  karim@gmail.com       | 2
---------------------------------------------------
```

I can retrieve data from one table and also from both table but can't show the counted data.

Comment: what is your try? or are you didn't google it before answering?

Comment: Not the `create table` statements; please show us the existing table with sample data and expected resultset.

Answer (score 1):

in any time use relation tables with int parameter
but no nchar for example in your tables relation with email --this is char column

```
create table #td_users
(id int not null identity(1,1),
 usename nchar(10),
 email nchar(20)
 )

 create table #td_add_service
(id int not null identity(1,1),
 serviceName nchar(10),
 serviceDeatails nchar(20),
 UserEmail nchar(20)
 )

 insert into #td_users(usename,email)
 values
 ('abdul','abdul@gmail.com'),
 ('Rahim ','rahim@gmail.com'),
 ('Karim ','karim@gmail.com');

 insert into #td_add_service(serviceName,serviceDeatails,UserEmail)
 values
 ('Servi1','testserviceone','abdul@gmail.com'),
('Servi11','testserviceonev','rahim@gmail.com'),
('Servi111','testserviceone1','karim@gmail.com'),
('Servi111','testserviceone2','karim@gmail.com');


select  tu.usename,
td.UserEmail,
count(td.serviceDeatails) [No of service] from #td_add_service td left join #td_users tu 
on td.UserEmail=tu.email
group by tu.usename,td.UserEmail order by 3


usename       UserEmail       No of service
abdul       abdul@gmail.com         1
Rahim       rahim@gmail.com         1
Karim       karim@gmail.com         2
```

Comment: can you please explain the select query? I am very new.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `td_users`.`UserName` AS Username, `td_users`.`UserEmail` AS UserMail, t2.countgroups AS NoOfServices FROM `td_users` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `id`,COUNT(*) AS countgroups FROM `td_add_service` GROUP BY `UserEmail`) t2 ON `td_users`.`id` = t2.`id`
```

I think this is what you asking.

Comment: Please see the problem again. I have cleared my issue .

Comment: I think that i am almost done. please look at a glance.

Comment: SELECT `td_users`.`UserName` AS Username, `td_users`.`UserEmail` AS UserMail, td_add_service.countgroups AS NoOfServices FROM `td_users` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `id`,COUNT(*) AS countgroups FROM `td_add_service` GROUP BY `id`) td_add_service ON `td_users`.`id` = td_add_service.`id`

Comment: @Rozario Sorry i got your question wrong. I thought `td_add_service`.`id` is the ids of users.. So i have grouped with ids. but This problem want to group with email. So change the `GROUP BY id` to `GROUP BY userEmail`